# Board game ai vs human using openai gym reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to use reinforcement learing to teach algorithm how to play board game hexxagon, [https://hexxagon.com/](https://stackoverflow.com). I was thinking about using openai gym to this purpose, but I have one concern about this idea. I've read that gym doesn't support multiple agents, so I came up with an idea to use minmax algorithm instead of second agent.
Is it possbile to use gym this way?
Second thing is that I wanted to use this agent later to make it play against human player. Is it possible to write environment in this way?

I've found couple examples of multiplayer board games using openai gym, like: [https://github.com/towzeur/gym-abalone](https://stackoverflow.com), [https://github.com/aigagror/GymGo](https://stackoverflow.com). This projects make me think it is possible to achieve my goal, but i want to make sure in the first place.

Comment: Multiple agents can be trained against each other. Have a look at the AlphaZero AI's, which are trained by playing itself and improving by itself. A Gym environment is a good template for building an environment anyways

Comment: Thanks for response @Lexpj do you know maybe is it possible to use this agent later to make it play against human in this environment?

Comment: Of course! Using the agent-environment loop you can make a move, then pass the state to the AI and will make its move, and will then in turn return the observation to you. Check out for example Stable Baselines 3, which shows how this loop works (in this case) for a DQN network: https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/dqn.html